# Apache performance tuning for high traffic with MPM Event

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, performance-tuning, mpm-event

I currently manage the following set of servers that serve about 700 web pages:

### SERVER 1 (WEB)

- **Web server**: Apache 2.4.29 with MPM Event
- **PHP 7.2.22**
- **CPU:** Intel Xeon CPU E5-2673 v4 @2.30GHz (4 cores) 16GB memory
- **S.O:** Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS

### SERVER 2 (DataBase)

- **DB:** mysql 10.2.26
- **CPU:** Intel Xeon CPU E5-2673 v4 @2.30GHz (8 cores) 32 GB memory
- **S.O:** Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS

Both servers are connected on the same local network.

Recurrently I have performance problems and I think it's because I don't have Apache optimized correctly.

The web server receives many web requests that it does not manage well and produces high CPU consumption and consequently slowness in the whole server.

Currently this is the MPM configuration I work with and I think it doesn't manage connections correctly:
[mpm event configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkV3L.png)

Can anyone tell me an optimal configuration of the MPM according to the requirements and characteristics of the server?

Thanks very much!

Comment: sorry for the necroposting, duplicate and answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823448/apache-performance-tuning-for-high-traffic-with-mpm-event